# How to estimate random error in a single measurement?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, standard-error

(from Jwan622's post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197725/how-can-we-calculate-the-standard-error-from-a-single-sample)),

This 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pVLm.png) was shown,
where we've got:

1. 19 samples (n = 19)
2. Mean of 4.4.
3. Sample standard deviation of 2.3 (s = 2.3)

If the standard error of mean from the sample is SE = s / sqrt(n) = 2.3 / sqrt(19),
and if I made one more measurement that had a value of 2, what would be the estimation of random error in that single measurement with 95% confidence?

Would that estimation be:

2 +/- (1.96 * [s + SE])?

The reason I ask is that a book [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=a_7IBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=maximum+likely+error+of+a+single+measurement&source=bl&ots=0z6OY3c1P_&sig=AQa1ZTgLyEPhvENQx676yxQO02U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLsIzY8M7ZAhVPMd8KHQfcCZ0Q6AEIODAC#v=onepage&q=maximum%20likely%20error%20of%20a%20single%20measurement&f=false) (2016, Morris, *Measurement and instrumentation*, 2nd edition) claims this is the case, but I was unable to independently verify it anywhere else.